# How can I make this effect with CSS3

Tags: html, css

How can I accomplish [this same effect](http://www.google.com/newproducts/) (the one below the Google logo and above the Nexus S image (it looks like a line with a subtle gradient coming out of it) using CSS3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `box-shadow` CSS3 property. Example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shaz/AQDcD/

Answer (score 0):

add box-shadow for an element mostly div,

box-shadow is dependent on browser so you need to add agent prefix while defining css look [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

`box-shadow` will not really work, Gecko (Firefox) and other browsers add the length of the shadow to the object and therefore create and overflow horizontally if you set the object to have full width or height. It's is best to use a CSS3 gradient background for this effect, it will save you having to hack the box-shadow not to overflow.